# SQL Query to join 2 tables with start/end dates

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables as described below :

```
DECLARE @Account TABLE
(   
    [AccountID] INT
    ,[Name] CHAR
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[EndDate] DATE
    ,[VATID] INT
);

DECLARE @VATRate TABLE
(   
    [VATID] INT
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[EndDate] DATE
    ,[Rate] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Account ([AccountID], [Name], [StartDate], [EndDate], [VATIT])
VALUES (1, 'Account A', '01.01.2023', '31.12.2024', 1)
      ,(2, 'Account B', '01.06.2022', NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO @VATRate ([VATID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [Rate])
VALUES (1, '01.01.2022', '31.12.2023', 7.7)
      ,(1, '01.01.2024', NULL, 8.1)
      ,(2, '01.01.2020', '31.12.2022', 3.5)
      ,(2, '01.01.2023', NULL, 4.2);
```

I want to write a query with a result table as shown below :

| AccountID | Name | A_StartDate | A_EndDate | Rate | T_StartDate | T_EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Account A | 01.01.2023 | 31.12.2024 | 7.7 | 01.01.2022 | 31.12.2023 |
| 1 | Account A | 01.01.2023 | 31.12.2024 | 8.1 | 01.01.2024 | NULL |
| 2 | Account B | 01.06.2022 | NULL | 3.5 | 01.01.2020 | 31.12.2022 |
| 2 | Account B | 01.06.2022 | NULL | 4.2 | 01.01.2023 | NULL |

I tried with a cross apply between the 2 tables but without any success. Any help ?

Comment: Please test your sample script, it's full of errors. You should also provide the sample data visually as a markdown table.

Comment: Are you able to change your end dates to being exclusive? For example if `January` is represented as `From 2022-01-01 up to but not including a 2022-02-01` then the maths becomes a ***lot*** cleaner. *(`February` would then be `2022-02-01 to 2022-03-01`, and `one day` on it's own would be `2022-03-01 to 2022-03-02`.)*

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: "I want to write a query....."   What did you try ?

Comment: Please correct any typo's in your question (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/m6sShPeN )

Answer (score 0):

Please do at least part of homework.

1. you dont have a valid example. (typos, wrong types)
2. [Rate] **DECIMAL(4,1)** -- **CANNOT BE INT DUE TO DECIMAL POINT**
   **3. learn joins.. and table priorities in joins**
3. learn **FORMAT function** for output...

I fixed input, and this example shows result as expected:

```
DECLARE @Account TABLE
(   
    [AccountID] INT
    ,[Name] varCHAR(50)
    ,[StartDate] DATE null
    ,[EndDate] DATE null
    ,[VATID] INT
);

DECLARE @VATRate TABLE
(   
    [VATID] INT
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[EndDate] DATE
    ,[Rate] DECIMAL(4,1) -- CANNOT BE INT DUE TO DECIMAL POINT
);

INSERT INTO @Account ([AccountID], [Name], [StartDate], [EndDate], [VATID])
VALUES (1, 'Account A', '2023-01-01', '2024-12-31', 1)
      ,(2, 'Account B', '2022-06-01', NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO @VATRate ([VATID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [Rate])
VALUES (1, '2022-01-01', '2023-12-31', 7.7)
      ,(1, '2024-01-01', NULL, 8.1)
      ,(2, '2020-01-01', '2022-12-31', 3.5)
      ,(2, '2023-01-01', NULL, 4.2);
      
select * from @account
select * from @VATRate


select 
    a.accountid
    , a.name 
    , A_StartDate = FORMAT(a.startdate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    , A_EndDate = FORMAT(a.EndDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    , t.Rate
    , T_StartDate = FORMAT(t.StartDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    , T_EndDate = FORMAT(t.EndDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
from @VATRate t
Left Join @account a on a.vatid = t.vatid
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EKWjmdsx)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You also don't take account if the start and end dates, at all

Comment: @MatBailie i did not see any requirements in OP related any filtering or additional logic. my result is matching requested.. IMHO.

Comment: in addition, dat5e format is belongs to different cultureinfo. so i used normal US dates. to convert from custom fomat there is an exampe: CONVERT(DATETime, '31.01.2023', 105)

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is universal.

Comment: Also, with regards to promoting the use of `FORMAT()` I suggest you read this; https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/

Comment: @MatBailie, good article, i am aware about performance of Format,(i think its can be used with "grain of salt".) i thought to use CONVERT(varchar,xxxxx,2) but it would return year 2 positions instead of 4 as in expected result and I was lazy to do substrings to match output format , so ui used FORMAT function. he he

Comment: 102 == 2 with four digits for the year (in most cases, just add 100)

Comment: he he. we can argue all day.. but 2024.02.20 - is not match to 01.01.2022 (requested in example output)

Comment: You mentioned format code 2, and noted it only has two year digits. I noted that to fix your complain you just add 100 to the code. If you want dd.MM.yyyy then the code is 104. If you don't mean to use code 2 or anything like it, ***don't bring it up***.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Account
(   
     [AccountID] INT
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(32)
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[EndDate] DATE
    ,[VATID] INT
);

CREATE TABLE VATRate
(   
     [VATID] INT
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[EndDate] DATE
    ,[Rate] MONEY
);

INSERT INTO Account ([AccountID], [Name], [StartDate], [EndDate], [VATID])
VALUES (1, 'Account A', '2023-01-01', '2025-01-01', 1)
      ,(2, 'Account B', '2022-06-01', NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO VATRate ([VATID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [Rate])
VALUES (1, '2022-01-01', '2024-01-01', 7.7)
      ,(1, '2024-01-01', NULL, 8.1)
      ,(2, '2020-01-01', '2023-01-01', 3.5)
      ,(2, '2023-01-01', NULL, 4.2);
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
  *,
  GREATEST(
    a.StartDate,
    v.StartDate
  ), 
  LEAST(
    ISNULL(a.EndDate, '9999-01-01'),
    ISNULL(v.EndDate, '9999-01-01')
  )
FROM
  Account   AS a
LEFT JOIN
  VATRate    AS v
    ON  v.VATId      = a.VATid
    AND (
         v.StartDate <  a.EndDate
      OR a.EndDate IS NULL
    )
    AND (
         v.EndDate   >  a.StartDate
      OR v.EndDate  IS NULL
    )
```

| AccountID | Name | StartDate | EndDate | VATID | VATID | StartDate | EndDate | Rate | (No column name) | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Account A | 2023-01-01 | 2025-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2024-01-01 | 7.7000 | 2023-01-01 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | Account A | 2023-01-01 | 2025-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 2024-01-01 | *null* | 8.1000 | 2024-01-01 | 2025-01-01 |
| 2 | Account B | 2022-06-01 | *null* | 2 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 3.5000 | 2022-06-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | Account B | 2022-06-01 | *null* | 2 | 2 | 2023-01-01 | *null* | 4.2000 | 2023-01-01 | 9999-01-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/acTFt6x2)

Comment: GREATEST is not recognized function in MS SQL. in versions prior 2022. since OP was not specified SQL version or brand.. its difficult to match or assume.

Comment: In those scenarios, CASE expressions exist.